# Most frequent log line from sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in SQL with 5 columns

```
Id
count
sector
server
log lines
```

I want to write a query that returns the most repeated log lines and the server it comes from

Note that the same log line can come from multiple servers.

I need something like this 
[image: something like this]

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (And take a look at [mcve].)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: 'Note that the same log line can come from multiple servers.' not sure why you felt the need to include this statement since the desired result  is by server,

Comment: Because the same log line can come from 5 different servers. So I want all the servers listed.

Comment: @jarlh. I uploaded an image to illustrated what I am trying to achieve

Comment: _all as formatted text, not images_...

Comment: Why does that expected result contain 2 'invalid user' logline?  Should it be group by the same logline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the top 3 repeated on MySql?

And assuming that the `count` column already contains a total?
Then it needs a `SUM` rather than a `COUNT`.

**Example:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE YourServerLogsTable
> (
>   Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `server` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
>   sector VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'dev',
>   `log lines` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
>   `count` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO YourServerLogsTable 
> (`server`, `log lines`, `count`) VALUES
> ('ACO101', 'Invalid foo', 103),
> ('ACO102', 'invalid Foo', 107),
> ('ACO101', 'invalid foo', 2),
> ('ACO101', 'bar was restarted', 104),
> ('ACO102', 'Bar was restarted', 102),
> ('ACO103', 'buz was here', 102),
> ('ACO104', 'Buz Was Here', 101),
> ('ACO101', 'humbag popsicle', 101),
> ('ACO102', 'humbag popsicle', 101);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     SELECT
>      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.`server` ORDER BY t.`count` DESC SEPARATOR ', ') AS `Servers`,
>      t.`log lines` AS `Logline`,
>      SUM(t.`count`) AS `Count`
>     FROM YourServerLogsTable t
>     GROUP BY t.`log lines`
>     ORDER BY SUM(t.`count`) DESC
>     LIMIT 3;
> ```
>
> ```
> Servers        | Logline           | Count
> :------------- | :---------------- | ----:
> ACO102, ACO101 | Invalid foo       |   212
> ACO101, ACO102 | bar was restarted |   206
> ACO103, ACO104 | buz was here      |   203
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=57015b2bfc292767d8e179246ed882f4)*

Comment: I am using mysql database

Comment: ok, but what about that `count` field? `SUM("count")` versus `COUNT(*)`.  And why the 2 'invalid user' in the expected result?

Comment: invalid user is a log line that came from the server

Comment: Naturally.  But we don't know how the data in your table looks like. So some simplified sample data could make it clear.  It just puzzles me that you want a top of repeated line, and the same line is twice in that result, while one would expect only 1 total.  So it seems that it's more than just grouping by the logline?

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you could use group by and group_concat()

```
select group_concat(server) server, log_lines, count(*) count_x_log_and_server
from my_table  
group by  log_lines
```

Comment: is  "count_x_log_and_server" a comment ?? You wrote group instead of group by or this was intentional?

Comment: answer  update  .. group by  (of course) ,.and count_x_log_and_server is column name alias